# Vagrant CHEF and EC2

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, amazon-ec2

I am using Vagrant to create a EC2 VM. My provisioner is CHEF.
My current challenge is to how to retrieve the VM public name while provisioning.

I've found that Ohai is capturing EC2 metadata and it is available during the provisioning. This is great. But, I can't seem to make Ohai capture the metadata.
According to [this article](http://geekblood.com/2015/03/13/enabling-ec2-metadata-in-ohai/), I need to create the ec2 hint file. 
Added the command to my CHEF recipe but it didn't work.

What is the right timing to create the hint file? A code snippet will be appreciated.

Comment: Use the shell provisionner of vagrant to create the file as per the documentation, before the the chef provisionner block, so it will be done before chef start...

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tensibai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3627607/tensibai) comment was helpful. It answered my question:

> Use the shell provisionner of vagrant to create the file as per the documentation, before the the chef provisionner block, so it will be done before chef start...